Batch file to copy from local drive to ftp
I need to create a .bat file which will copy an excel spreadsheet to an ftp folder. I am able to do this manually by dragging and dropping the xls file. I know how to set up windows task scheduler to run the .bat file

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Use curl to upload your file(s) utilizing TFP protocol
curl -T '{file1,file2}' ftp://ftp.example.com/upload/

Thank you. That seems to be working. I have scheduled for the .bat file to be scheduled from the windows task manager. If there are any issues, I will let you know user2956477

than mark my anwer as issue solving please, thank you

I had to make a change to the windows scheduler, now the file is not longer being copied. It also does not work if I run it manually. Here is what I have.: Can you please take a look and let me know where I have gone wrong:
curl -T '{C:\Users\psupport\Documents\Exports for SRS\ManufacturersInventory\Manufacturers Inventory.xls, Manufacturers Inventory.xls}' ftps://scr.genicad.cz/uploads/

change quoting in following manner: curl -T "{'C:\Users\psupport\Documents\Exports for SRS\ManufacturersInventory\Manufacturers Inventory.xls','Manufacturers Inventory.xls'}" ftps://scr.genicad.cz/uploads/

Thank you for your response, but this is also not working. I need to upload just a single xls spreadsheet from 'C:\Users\psupport\Documents\Exports for SRS\ManufacturersInventory\Manufacturers Inventory.xls' to the ftp folder
